# Validate the score in python

Tags: python

```
array = []
total = 0

text = int(input("How many students in your class: "))
print("\n")
while True:
        for x in range(text):
                score = int(input("Input score {} : ".format(x+1)))
                if score <= 0 & score >= 101:
                        break
                print(int(input("Invalid score, please re-enter: ")))
                array.append(score)

print("\n")

print("Maximum: {}".format(max(array)))
print("Minimum: {}".format(min(array)))
print("Average: {}".format(sum(array)/text))
```

I tried to make a python program, to validate the score, but it's still a mistake, I want to make a program if I enter a score of less than 0 it will ask to re-enter the score as well if I input more than 100. Where is my error?

Comment: Your logic is wrong. For one thing, you want to break if the score >= 0, not <= 0, for example. For another, `&` is not the same as `and`. Try `if 0 <= score <= 100:`, with *comparison chaining*.

Comment: One point: `score` can't be at the same time less than or equal to 0 and greater than or equal to 101 (if you meant `&` as `and`).

Comment: Also your loops are the wrong way around.

Comment: @jonrsharpe is the answer OK?

Comment: yes @jonrsharpe

Comment: @HOLA try https://stackoverflow.com/a/61251033/13062813

Comment: @Bhupeshlad Thanks, but that feature will never be implemented because votes are to be anonymous

Comment: I'm new in Stackoverflow, so if I post wrong please forgive

Comment: And Thank you, everyone, for helping me today.

Comment: And btw what is "Downvotes"?

Comment: @HOLA if my answer helped you, dont forget to click the tick next to my answer. and for what is downvote, refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: Okey thank you @JoshuaVarghese

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the if statement:

```
array = []
total = 0

text = int(input("How many students in your class: "))
print("\n")
for x in range(text):
        score = int(input("Input score {} : ".format(x+1)))
        while True:
                if 0 <= score <= 100:
                        break
                score = int(input("Invalid score, please re-enter: "))
         array.append(score)

print("\n")

print("Maximum: {}".format(max(array)))
print("Minimum: {}".format(min(array)))
print("Average: {}".format(sum(array)/text))
```

---

Here, the `score` at the same time can't be less than 0 and greater than 100. So as you want to break of the score is between 0 and 100, we use `0 <= score <= 100` as the `break`ing condition.

Also the loops were reversed, since you won't get what you expected to.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
array = []
total = 0

num_of_students = int(input("How many students in your class: "))
print("\n")
for x in range(num_of_students):
    score = int(input("Input score {} : ".format(x + 1)))
    while True:
        if score < 0 or score > 100:
            score = int(input("Invalid score, please re-enter: "))
        else:
            array.append(score)
            break


print("\n")
print("Maximum: {}".format(max(array)))
print("Minimum: {}".format(min(array)))
print("Average: {}".format(sum(array)/num_of_students))
```

Answer (score 0):

I renamed some of your variables. You should always try to using self explanatory variable names. I am also using string interpolation (should be possible for Python +3.6) and comparison chaining.

```
score_list = []
total = 0

number_of_students = int(input("How many students in your class: "))

print("\n")
for student in range(number_of_students):
    score_invalid = True
    while score_invalid:
        score_student = int(input(f"Input score {student + 1} : "))
        if (0 <= score_student <= 100):
            score_invalid = False
        else:
            score_invalid = True
        if score_invalid:
            print("Invalid score!\n")
    score_list.append(score_student)

print("\n")

print(f"Maximum: {max(score_list)}")
print(f"Minimum: {min(score_list)}")
print(f"Average: {sum(score_list) / number_of_students}")
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like this:

```
score = -1
first_time = True

while type(score) != int or score <= 0 or score >= 101  :
    if first_time:
        score = int(input("Input score: "))
        first_time = False
    else:
        score = int(input("Invalid score, please re-enter: "))

array.append(score)
```

Comment: I did't downvote you. But your code is not complete. You do not have the array to append to and you are appending outside of the loop, hence you should only append the last score.

Comment: @MachineLearner, you are right! Thanks for giving the feedback. Reading the question back now, I realize that a score per student should be entered. The snippet above only tests the validity of entering a single score.